# How to setup PHP Controller

Tags: php, methods, controller

Im giving support to an already deployed php application, but the way it works is new to me, and I have no idea how it does what it does.

Basically, a php method is called using a path-like syntax to retrieve data, for example:

```
<?php
// .....
$json = Request("http://_server/myfolder/abc/default/mymethod?data=something");
// Now $json var has some information.
?>
```

The odd thing is how methods are structured. Up to folder 'myfolder' physical path exists in linux 'server', you know ".../apache/htdocs/myfolder/" but thats IT. Further than that, physical location of code is within a different folder structure where **default/mymethod** matches NO folders at all.

By digging deeper, I found that **mymethod** corresponds to the PHP method located in:

```
apache/htdocs/myfolder/protected/modules/abc/controllers/defaultcontroller.php
```

And inside defaultcontroller.php there is something like this:

```
<?php
// ....
Class DefaultController {
    // ....
    Public Function actionmymethod { // Notice the name of mymethod has 'action'
        // more code
        return $response;
    }
}
?>
```

Im 100% sure that method is fired when running the Request call, but my I dont know how it is done.

My question is:

How the setup of this is done? There must be some place where you relate:

```
"http://_server/myfolder/abc/default/mymethod" with "actionmethod"
```

but where and how?

I need to make a copy of this running, so I can call my copy with something like this:

```
"http://_server/FOLDERCOPY/myfolder/abc/default/mymethod"
```

I already made a copy to the new structure, but when calling it, server cant find the new method/path :(

EDIT***
I found this in htaccess located at /myfolder/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myfolder/ 

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I modified the copy inside /FOLDERCOPY/myfolder, but it seems is not working :(

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /FOLDERCOPY/myfolder/ 

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: Basically it looks like this application is multi-tiered.  The parts that are doing the Request calls, are using a client http library that is making an HTTP request to the url.  The url is returning data in json format.  Now to the rest of the framework, you should look at the index.php in the doc root of the server.  It no doubt is bootstrapping the framework, and from there you should be able to trace what the components of it are.

Comment: In terms of your controllers, an action is simply a handler name.  Somewhere there is going to be a routing configuration that links a particular route to that action name.  Once you figure out what framework they used, you should be able to find some documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not every url is mapped 1:1 to the server's filesystem.

Apparently, there should be a php script inside `.../apache/htdocs/myfolder/`, most probably an `index.php`. There should also be some rewrite rules, probably in a `.htaccess` file, that translate urls under `http://_server/myfolder` to that script, tranforming the remaining part to parameters (either a `query_string` or a `path_info`).

From this point on, php takes over. The structure implies the existence of an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework. This framework appears to support modules, one of them being `abc`, whose `default` controller's `mymethod` method is called to handle the request. So the url structure is like this:

```
http://server/site/module/controller/method?params
```

Look for a config file under `.../apache/htdocs/myfolder/` (`config.php`?). It will contain rules as to the modules' location and the mappings (routing) to controllers. Then again, there may be a global site config, as well as one for each module...

Comment: there is a rewriterule, but seem cant make it work :(

Comment: @Paris Create a `test.php` file inside `/FOLDERCOPY/myfolder` containing `<?php echo "hello";` and change `index.php` into `test.php` in the relevant `.htaccess`. What's the outcome?

Comment: I have in my .htaccess the same as above, but with test.php
RewriteBase /FOLDERCOPY/myfolder/ 
RewriteRule . test.php

Im calling example.com/FOLDERCOPY/myfolder/whatever
Server says The Requested URL is not found

Comment: I think the problem is I have TWO .htaccess files, one in /myfolder/ and the other in /FOLDERCOPY/myfolder. How can I have both rules without interfering with each other?

Comment: @Paris I think you have to read up on [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).